# Swipe between two pages with Segmented-style Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uipageviewcontroller, uiviewrepresentable

I have a `Picker` with `.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())` to make it a segmented control. I want to make the pages smoothly swipe between, rather than replacing the view using a conditional statement.

Here is a gif of what I have made so far:

[image: What I have made]

Here is the code so far (controlled by an `if`, instead of switching between different pages):

```
struct AuthView: View {

    @State private var authPath = 0

    /* ... */

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $authPath, label: Text("Authentication Path")) {
                Text("Log In").tag(0)
                Text("Sign Up").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Spacer()

            if authPath == 0 {
                LogInView(/* ... */)
            } else {
                SignUpView(/* ... */)
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color("Color.Background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}
```

I want something similar to [`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller). If there is a SwiftUI version or a good alternative, that would really help.

However, if I do need to resort to UIKit with `UIViewRepresentable`, I don't know how I would implement it with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These other answers pointed me in the right direction, but the code seems a bit verbose or didn't function as intended.

Here is what changed to get mine working:

- Padding was added to the `Picker`.
- Padding was removed from the end of the `VStack`.
- The `if-else` was changed to 2 `if`s.
- Added `animation`, `transition`, and `padding` modifiers to each of `LogInView` and `SignInView`.

#### Original:

```
struct AuthView: View {

    @State private var authPath = 0

    /* ... */

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $authPath, label: Text("Authentication Path")) {
                Text("Log In").tag(0)
                Text("Sign Up").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Spacer()

            if authPath == 0 {
                LogInView(/* ... */)
            } else {
                SignUpView(/* ... */)
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color("Color.Background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}
```

#### New:

```
struct AuthView: View {

    @State private var authPath = 0

    /* ... */

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $authPath, label: Text("Authentication Path")) {
                Text("Log In").tag(0)
                Text("Sign Up").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding()

            Spacer()

            if authPath == 0 {
                LogInView(/* ... */)
                    .animation(.default)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                    .padding()
            }
            if authPath == 1 {
                SignUpView(/* ... */)
                    .animation(.default)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                    .padding()
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color("Color.Background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I managed to achieve this by creating both `Picker` and `TabView` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedPage: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $selectedPage) {
                Text("First").tag(0)
                Text("Second").tag(1)
                Text("Third").tag(2)
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
                
            TabView(selection: $selectedPage) {
                FirstView().tag(0)
                    
                SecondView().tag(1)
                    
                ThirdView().tag(2)
            }.tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
}
```

Both of the `Picker` and `TabView` share the same selection state so when the `Picker` get selected or the `TabView` get scrolled, the other changed as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible approach (please note, for testing it needs to use Simulator, because Preview does not handle `.move` transitions correctly)

Demo (just used stub views, the parameters of animation and transition can be configured, but the idea remains the same).

Note: background of transitioning view should be opaque (here `Color.white` is used), otherwise transitions look... not good.

[image: SwiftUI move view transition]

```
struct TestTwoViewMoveIn: View {
    @State private var authPath: Int? = nil

    /* ... */

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: Binding<Int>(
                get: { self.authPath ?? 0 },
                set: { tag in
                    withAnimation { // needed explicit for transitions
                        self.authPath = tag
                    }
                }),
                   label: Text("Authentication Path")) {
                Text("Log In").tag(0)
                Text("Sign Up").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Spacer()

            ZStack {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
                if nil == authPath {
                    LogInView(/* ... */)
                        .background(Color.white) // << set your background 
                }

                if authPath == 0 {
                    LogInView(/* ... */)
                        .background(Color.white) // << set your background 
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                }

                if authPath == 1 {
                    SignUpView(/* ... */)
                        .background(Color.white) // << set your background 
                        .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                }
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color("Color.Background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap `LoginView` and `SignupView` inside some container to make it animate.

```
                 var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Picker(selection: $authPath, label: Text("Authentication Path")) {
              //  withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut.speed(0.5)){
                Text("Log In").tag(0)
                    Text("Sign Up").tag(1)}
                //}
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Spacer()


            if authPath == 0 {
               NavigationView{
                Text("1")
                }.animation(.default).transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                //(/* ... */)
            } else {
                NavigationView{
                Text("2")
                }.animation(.default).transition(.move(edge: .leading))

             //(/* ... */)

                }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color("Color.Background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
```